# After I verify number of digits is equal to 5,I want back unchanged n value

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to verify whether entered number has 5 digit or not so I use while loop for this.

```
while(n>=10)
{
    n = n/10;
    count++;
}
if(count != 5)
    return 0;
```

But next parts of my code are using updated n value and I don't want that.How can I say "use first n value" to my code?Here is all my code(It works smoothly when I delete configuration part):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int digit=0,n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>=10)
    {
        n = n/10;
        count++;
    }
    if(count != 5)
        return 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        digit += n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("%d",digit);     
}
```

Comment: Use another variable like `int tempn = n;`

Comment: Note that your loop undercounts the number of digits; if you enter `n` as `5`, for example, then `count` is never incremented, so it stays at 0.  You should probably initialize `count` to `1` (or switch to a `do`…`while` loop.  You should check that `scanf()` succeeds, too.  Also, returning zero from `main()` indicates success; you probably shouldn't indicate success when your checking fails.  You should probably also report the error with a message.  And you should definitely end your printing with a newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in bigger projects we call it 1/100 reproducible bug until tester identifies correct input to reproduce the bug. Its nightmare.

Comment: Make a function like `int digitCount(int n) { ... }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I just recognize when it didn't work :D Thanks for tips .But how can I say "If this loop is entered stop working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different temporary variable for error checking.
This way your original variable will be intact.

```
int temp = n;
while(temp>=10)
{
    temp = temp/10;
    count++;
}
```